# Are non-Jews/gentiles permanent slaves to Jews in Olam Habah?

Tags: gentiles, slave-serve-eved-avadim, olam-haba-world-to-come

Are non-Jews permanent slaves to Jews in the world to come? I'll post the source text once I find it, or if someone can edit this and post the source for me. I believe it's in the Talmud, but not sure what tractate.

As a ben Noach and self-aware human being, I find this is concerning.

Comment: Are you asking if every non-Jew becomes a slave, or if non-Jewish slaves (ie Eved Kenani) remain slaves then?

Comment: Hrm, I'd have to read the section of the tractate. If it's "Eved Kenani" then that just means Canaanite and not all or even most non-Jews, which changes my perpective, yet with more questions. So, I guess this question is still valid, but you raise another question I could post, which is "Are all non-Jews going to be slaves in the world to come" or something.

Comment: As a Jew, I too find this concerning.

Comment: Why "non-Jews/gentiles"?  Why not just "non-Jews" or "gentiles" alone?  They are the same thing, so it is redundant.

Comment: To help with search engine optimization

Comment: Re: SEO, that's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps we need to start by defining what the word *eved* means in Judaism anyway. It [doesn't necessarily mean slavery or servility](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6087/37); in the Bible it is frequently used of royal ministers (and even in one instance - see the answer I linked - King Rehoboam is advised to "be an *eved* to the people"). Great figures in Jewish history - Moses, Joshua, David - are described as "the *eved* of G-d," and more generally, the Jewish people collectively are called His *avadim*.

In all of these cases, the idea is that the person so described is devoted to a higher purpose, and becomes elevated thereby. (The Talmud, Shevuos 47b, comments that "the *eved* of a king is himself like a king.")

In the era of Moshiach, "the occupation of the entire world will be solely to know G-d" ([Rambam, Laws of Kings 12:5](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188357/jewish/Chapter-12.htm)), and in particular, "the Jews will be great sages and know the hidden matters, grasping the knowledge of their Creator according to the full extent of human potential" (ibid.). So while "the Sages and the prophets did not yearn for the Messianic era in order to have dominion over the entire world, to rule over the gentiles, to be exalted by the nations..." (ibid. 12:4), the point is that the peoples of the world will themselves realize that it is an honor and a privilege to be "servants to the servants of G-d" (a title used by R. Akiva Eiger, one of the great sages of the past couple of centuries) - to do whatever they can to create the optimal conditions for "G-d's *avadim*" to do their work.

Comment: To add, one of the standard way of referring to public leaders is "public servants"

Answer (score 7):

[Avodah Zarah 10b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=10b&format=pdf) quotes Antoninus as wanting to serve Rabbi in olam haba. Rabbi tells him that descendants of Esav who don't think like Esav are not included in "there won't be a remainder to Esav" ([Ovadiah 1:18](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1601.htm#18)).

Comment: That's a good read and it helps me fill in some missing pieces. I can't seem to find the tractate I remember reading. It must be in another text.

Answer (score 7):

In the Messianic era the nations will recognize and facilitate Israel's role as a priestly nation. The imagery used by the **Bible** *suggests* servitude, "Foreigners will stand and tend your locks and the sons of the stranger will be you plowmen and your vineyard workers. And you will be called 'priests of Hashem"' "ministers of our G-d" will be said of you. You will eat of the wealth of nations and will pride yourselves in their glory." (Isaiah 61:5-6, Artscroll), nevertheless I think that the main point is that the nations will view the Jewish people as their clergy rather than as their masters.

Comment: Reminicent of Bnei Yisrael supporting the Kohanim.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Noahide. Jews viewing non-Jews as slaves is a pervasive, if not prominent, view. For example, Rabbi Ovadia Yosef was infamous for boldly [stating](https://web.archive.org/web/20101020044210/http://www.jpost.com/JewishWorld/JewishNews/Article.aspx?id=191782)

> "Goyim were born only to serve us. Without that, they have no place in the world"

Yet he had thousands of students, was honored numerous times and served as the Chief Sephardic Rabbi of Israel for ten years. Even in death he is [referred to](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/rabbi-ovadia-yosef) as "...one of the foremost Talmudic authorities of his generation." ["...there has never been a rabbi as great as him."](https://www.reuters.com/article/israel-rabbi/some-700000-attend-funeral-of-revered-israeli-rabbi-idINDEE9960DP20131007/)

Contrast that with another Sephardic Rabbi, [Maimonides](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188353/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-8.htm):

> "Anyone who accepts upon himself the fulfillment of these seven mitzvot and is precise in their observance is considered one of "the pious among the gentiles" and will merit a share in the world to come."

And the oft-quoted section from the [Talmud](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.39b.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> "...a gentile who engages in Torah study is considered like a High Priest."

The Noahide Laws have only one positive command: Establish courts of justice. No slave does that. No slave creates a court system, appoints judges, decides matters of civil and religious law. God gave Noahides seven laws, and [Maimonides said](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188353/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-8.htm), "...through Moses our Teacher we were informed that the Sons of Noah had already been commanded to observe them." Had God commanded the sons of Noah to serve the Jews, I'm sure He would have informed us first.

A Noahide man is a free man.

Comment: The question was regarding Olam Haba, the world to come. Your first source doesn't discuss Olam Haba but this world, and as such doesn't answer the question

Comment: @mbloch Makes no difference. Clearly Gentiles are not slaves to Jews today. If you think Olam Haba will change that, I'm glad to learn.