# Who is the nation/kingship of Edom?

Tags: christianity, daniel-book-of, esav

There are/were 4 kingship's (malchuyos) described in Sefer Daniel. Edom, being one of them (I think?), is often explained to be the Roman Empire.

1- What is the source to say that Edom was the Roman Empire?

2- Now that the Roman Empire no longer exists, who is said to be Edom?

3- Is there any connection between Christianity and Edom?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6076/are-europeans-edomites http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29847/why-is-edom-considered-to-be-western-culture-and-not-southern-jordan

Comment: The bulk of this question is a duplicate of the linked-to question. I suggest you read the answers there and, if you still have a question, come back here and [edit] this to reflect what you're still wondering (or ask a new question instead if you prefer).