# Why is Esav identified with the European people?

Tags: history

This question is for the history buffs. Do you know why we say Esav is Rome and Esav is modern day European descendants?

Comment: Related: "[Are Europeans Edomites](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6076/1368)"?

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.27.39?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en

> וַיַּ֛עַן יִצְחָ֥ק אָבִ֖יו וַיֹּ֣אמֶר אֵלָ֑יו הִנֵּ֞ה מִשְׁמַנֵּ֤י
> הָאָ֙רֶץ֙ יִהְיֶ֣ה מֽוֹשָׁבֶ֔ךָ וּמִטַּ֥ל הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם מֵעָֽל׃
>
> And ῾Esav raised his voice, and wept. And Yiżĥaq his father answered
> and said to him, Behold, thy dwelling shall be of the fatness of the
> earth, and of the dew of heaven from above;

And in Rashi

> משמני ארץ וגו'. זוֹ אִיטָלִיאָה שֶׁל יָוָן:
>
> Of the fatness of the earth: This refers to Italy.

See also Megillah 6a, where the gemara refers to a tribe called Germamia that comes from Esav, which Rb Yaakov Emden corrects to Germania (Germany).

http://www.yahadoot.net/item.asp?cid=12&id=582

> "ואמר רבי יצחק: מאי דכתיב (תהילים קט): "אל תתן ה' מאויי רשע, זממו אל
> תפק ירומו סלה"? אמר יעקב לפני הקב"ה: 'ריבונו של עולם אל תתן לעשו הרשע
> תאוות לבו. "זממו אל תפק" - זו גרממיא של אדום, שאלמלי הם יוצאים [הם]
> מחריבים כל העולם כולו".
>
> הרב יעקב עמדין (היעב"ץ), שחי לפני כ־250 שנה, כתב: ״גרממיא״, רצונו לומר
> 'גרמניא' היא אשכנז שלנו. וכן הגאון מוילנא כתב שצריך לגרוס: ״גרמניא״.

Comment: This is a good answer, and just as importantly a great source, but would be incredibly useful to show how we identify all of Italy with Rome and the entirety of Western Civilization with Rome.

Comment: @יהושעק I added another source. Generally the Rishonim seem to identify Europe with Esav, for unclear reasons.

Comment: Great, much obliged, @pcoz. This question seems to come up from time to time so I thought it best to make the connection explicit.

Comment: @יהושעק Because Rome was the most powerful country in Europe for a very, very long time, and still has a massive influence on Western society.