# Who are the Sinnites?

Tags: midrash, geography, modern-times

In Modern Hebrew, china is refered to as סין(Sin). There are three mentions of סין throughout tanach:

> ויסעו מאלים ויבאו כל עדת בני ישראל אל מדבר סין אשר בין אילים ובין
> סיני, בחמשה עשר יום לחדש השני לצאתם מארץ מצרים.

> They traveled from Eilim and all of the congregation of Israel came to the desert of Sin, which is between Eilim and Sinai, on the 15th day to the second month of their leaving Egypt.

(שמות טז א)

> הנה אלה מרחוק יבאו והנה אלה מצפון ומים ואלה מארץ סינים.

> Behold these will come from afar, and behold these from the north and from the sea, and these from the land of the Sinnites.

(ישעיה מט יב)

> ושפכתי את חמתי על סין מעוז מצרים, והכרתי את המון נא...

> I will pour out my wrath on Sin, the stronghold of Egypt, and destroy the multitudes of No.

(יחזקאל ל טו)

The medrash lekach tov (on the passuk in parshas shelach ויעלו ויתורו את הארץ ממדבר סין) says

> "סין, הוא צין הוא סין הוא פארן הוא קדמות. צין שנצטוו שם ישראל על המצוות, סין שבו באת שנאה לאומות העולם, פארן שבו פרו ישראל, קדמות שבו קבלו את התורה שהיא קדומה לעולם,שנאמר..."

> Sin is Tzin/Zin which is Paran which is Kedemoth. Tzin because in it the jews were commanded on the commandments, Sin because in it comes anger to the nations, Paran because in it Israel were fruitful, Kedemoth because in it they accepted the Torah which came before the world, as it says...

1. The Targum Yonasan says that ארץ סינים is the south. The radak agrees and says that they are from the children of Canaan.
2. He quotes Rabbi Saadya Gaon saying that it is "אטרא בלפיון"(Atra Balafyon? Atra in Lafyon? Atra in Lapion? [Hatra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatra?wprov=sfla1)? (ancient city in the Nineveh Governorate of present-day Iraq)).
3. The abarbanel says that they are the children of Yonadav son of Reichav, who rashi says was from the children of Jethro (Yisro).
4. The Ibn Ezra says they are Egypt.

So which one is it? Who is this nation? What is "אטרא בלפיון"? What was the medrash referring to?

Comment: Also related: [Did Chazal know about China and the Chinese? And from which of Noach's sons do they hail?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26988/did-chazal-know-about-china-and-the-chinese-and-from-which-of-noachs-sons-do-t?noredirect=1&lq=1)