# Where is הגר? The country, not the person

Tags: geography

In the [מטה אשר](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=12) (commentary to שמלה חדשה), it is recorded that it was the custom of Jews in "מדינות מלכות רוסיא וגאלציא וגם במדינת הגר בקהילת היראים" to use the sefer שמלה חדשה to learn the halachos of shechita. So I figured out (big deal) that רוסיא is Russia, and גאלציא is Galicia; but what/where is הגר?

Comment: By the way, I strongly suspect גאלציא is the Polish Galicia, not the Spanish Galicia. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galicia .)

Comment: @msh210 no question about it! I and many are from Galitzia in eastern Europe as are all the places mentioned.

Comment: "בקהילת היראים" what does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hungary.

See this matzeva from Sighet, Hungary

http://books.google.com/books?id=MF8LAAAAIAAJ&pg=PP11&lpg=PP11&dq=%22%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%92%D7%A8%22&source=bl&ots=XTrztOSUE_&sig=99MotorIcpDDGH2q2_SjH6ao6Zo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rSdnU7jhKbK0sQS15IHQCw&ved=0CC0Q6AEwBDgK

Answer (score 8):

Yoni beat me to it, but I found a source if you'd like one: the Targum on Tehillim 83:7 translated "הגרים" as "הונגראי".

The term is used so often all over Jewish literature to refer to Hungary though that a source isn't really needed. (In fact, the translation offered by Targum there is highly unlikely to be correct; just thought it was a cool tidbit)

Comment: Very nice! This also appears in the Targum to 1 Chronicles 5:10 (although note that Jastrow understands it to be a reference to the inhabitants of Hagra, an Arabian district).

Comment: @ShimonbM - I love the early reference from the Targum. Similar to your comment, I wonder if interpreting the Targum as referring to Hungary is anachronistic, or perhaps this just attests to the late authorship of the Targum on Kesuvim. As far as the text from Tehillim or Divrei Hayamim referring Hungary, that is almost certainly an anachronism since Hungary was apparently not so name until about the 9th century.(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magyar_tribes)

Comment: Relevant? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1830/5323