# What are the major regions relevant to Ashkenazi minhagim?

Tags: minhag, history, ashkenazi, geography

Motivating this question are the instructions in the ArtScroll Siddur for the two versions of *kel erekh apayim*, said on weekdays before taking out the *sefer torah*: one is identified as “נוסח אשכנז, פיהם, ופולין קטן”, the other as “נוסח פולין גדל וליטא”. Similarly, *selichos* are listed as “מנהג פולין” or “מנהג ליטא”.

My question is in two parts:

- What do “פיהם”‎, “פולין גדל”‎, “פולין קטן”‎, “ליטא”‎, *etc.* specifically refer to? and (more importantly)
- When classifying Ashkenazi *minhagim*, which regions of Europe are significant?

(By “significant” I might [for example] include Frankfurt am Main [ק״ק פפד״מ] since its *minhagim* were historically important and distinct from elsewhere in the Germanies, but the simple fact that the one-horse town of Magyaslozckin had some unique *minhagim* of its own would *not* rate it a mention.)

Comment: Related? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37799/5323

Comment: Definitely related: a proper answer to my question would cover הגר=Hungary.

Comment: The ideal answer would enable someone to find his ancestors’ home town on a map of Europe, look up what region this was in during (*e.g.*) the 1600s, and identify the general set of relevant _minhagim_. [NBZ’s answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45968/70) is a very good start.

Answer (score 6):

The very influential and authoritative Ashkenazi *[Siddur Sfat Emet](http://www.talmud.de/tlmd/siddur-sefat-emet/)* and its associated *machzorim* and *chumash* include references to two distinct major minhagim corresponding to the ones specified by ArtScroll:

1. *Polnischer Ritus* (Polish rites) = נוסח פולין גדל וליטא and מנהג פולין
2. *Deutscher Ritus* (German rites) = נוסח אשכנז, פיהם, ופולין קטן and מנהג ליטא

and *Frankfurt am Main* (ק״ק פפד״מ) as subset of 2.

Despite their names, they are referring to a longitudinally (east-west) very broad latitudinal (north-south) division, where 1. is north, and 2. is south. It spans all of northern Europe, thus spanning at least from the Rhineland to the Baltic states.* Thus, Hamburg is in "Poland"!

Besides *Kel Erekh Apayim*, and *Selichos*, other differences are:

- Order of *Avinu Malkeinu*
- Order of morning blessings
- *Haftora* selection
- *Sim Shalom*/*Shalom Rav* dependency
- Inclusion of certain *V'yiten lecha* passages

[Source: My family is from the area, and that siddur and those minhagim are still in use there. I just visited for Rosh Hashana and went over it again.]

---

<sup>* E.g. 1. includes the northern [Greater Poland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_Poland) (פולין גדל), whereas 2. includes the southern [Lesser Poland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesser_Poland) (פולין קטן).</sup>

Comment: If you are looking for a siddur for מנהג פוליןת I suggest looking at the מחזור פולין מכול השנה.

Answer (score 5):

First, read up on the Polish-Lithuanian Commonwealth. It is very interesting and plays a big role in Jewish historiy, especially vis a vis the Russians.

ליטא is Lithuania and most likely corresponds to the part south of the grey area on this map. (Polish borders were extremely dynamic)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rzeczpospolita2nar.png

The two polands are regions of Poland (see links)
פיהם is Yiddish for Bohemia  (Pihm)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_European_regions_with_alternative_names

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesser_Poland
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_Poland

Other important ashkenazi regions throughout Jewish history include the Rhineland and the Pale (Pale of Settlement)