# Ashkenazi Haftarah Custom

Tags: minhag, geography, ashkenazi, haftarah

On Wikipedia, there is a [list of haftarot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haftarah#List_of_Haftarot).

For Ashkenazim, the list gives four customs: Ashkenazi, Polish, Frankfurt, and Chabad. Considering that Polish and Frankfurt sum up the major non-chassidic opinions, what is the opinion which is referred to only as "Ashkenazi"?

Comment: Related? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45891/5323

Comment: "questions about what others have written about Judaism, are off-topic on Mi Yodeya" reads the closure reason. How should we know what Wikipedia means by that? Ask [Dovi](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/user_talk:Dovi), who [introduced that notation to the article](//en.wikipedia.org/?diff=3976570&diffonly=1).

Answer (score 1):

I clicked through your link to the WP page; I think you're misreading the chart.

I don't think there are four sets of customs there; I think the list will write "A" for Ashkenaz when all three customs (Frankfurt, Chabad, and Poland) are the same, but is ready to use those letters to differentiate them when they're not the same.

I haven't checked that list against a list of minhagim (for example, what might be found in a Chumash), but I'm reasonably certain that I'm right.

Comment: Although, WP *does* say that the list is incomplete....

Comment: Well, the list would be incomplete, what with all of the unwritten customs from shtetlach or villages in the Middle East and North Africa.

Comment: However, my comment, was more where there was an instance of A, then AP and AF were different from that (I forget what Chabad was on)

Comment: Like for Breishit (cc @NoachmiFrankfurt).