# Angels in Bohemia?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In the morning *birchos krias shema‘*, in discussing the angels’ song of praise, the text makes an odd digression:

> וכולם פותחים את פיהם
>   *and they all open Pihm* (= *Bohemia*)

(See *[What are the major regions relevant to Ashkenazi minhagim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45891/70)* for the identification.)

But what are the angels doing in Bohemia?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/797/70).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is that there are many voices singing in unison, so it is a direct reference to a Bohemian harmony, or a [Bohemian Rhapsody](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-ARuoSFflc) if you will.

This special prayer has the power to block all bad stemming from Baal Zvuv, commonly called Baalzebub.

It is also brings to mind the ability for us to cry out in despair Mamamia!, Mamamia!

Comment: Great use of R' Freddie Mercury

Comment: @Noach zchuso yagin aleinu

Comment: I was thinking of voting for this answer, maybe accepting it, but nothing really matters…

Comment: @J.C. Salomon any way the wind blows.......:)