# Any books dealing with minhaggim of Lita?

Tags: minhag, product-recommendation, jewish-books, ashkenazi, chutz-laaretz

Are there any books that discuss the varying Litvish (Lithuanian) minhaggim (customs)—or, if not, maybe just the most prevalent ones?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! You might want to check out this related question http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45891/5323
 as well. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 7):

[Minhagei Lita (Customs of Lithuanian Jewry) by Rabbi Menachem Mendel Poliakoff](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0083WUQ7Y).

---

It should be noted that this work has been critiqued as reflecting the author's personal experiences, not historic Lithuania as a whole. See http://seforim.blogspot.com/2009/10/review-minhagei-lita.html.

Comment: +1 but http://seforim.blogspot.com/2009/10/review-minhagei-lita.html

Comment: +1 This rabbi attended the original Telshe yeshiva in Lithuania in the 1930's. Because of this, he is able to point out things that we *think* are standard Litvak customs, but are actually post-war borrowings from Hasidic or other Jewish customs. Quite interesting. I got to read this book via inter-library loan, and was *so* pleased when the libraries shipped it from New York to Ohio, just for me to read!

Comment: To make @ShmuelBrin's implication more explicit, from the bottom of the linked post: "I have learned that this book was never intended to be a presentation of minhagei Lita, Telshe, or any other customs."

Comment: @WAF Like one of the commenters there, "I think you mean something like 'was never intended to be a complete presentation'. Hard to believe it wasn't intended to address the topic at all."

Comment: @mevaqesh Right. That would be comical/surreal. More so than us having their proxy conversation here. . . Without belittling the historical value of a book I've never read, I think the criticism in the main thrust of the post deserves note WRT to its lack of support for being a source of either "varying" or "prevalent" _minhagim_.

Comment: @WAF Would you prefer that I add the caveat that the book is based on personal experiences and not historical research of broader Lithuania?