# Slavic People are called K'nan in jewish sources

Tags: history, gentiles, words, language, canaan

Why is the slavic languages or people reffered to as Cannanim in Jewish sources? Who is the first to do this?

See for instance Minchas Yehuda in Mechokekei Yehuda explaining Rashi on Devarim 3:9 [Here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39774&st=&pgnum=31&hilite=).
Minchas Yehuda says this was a common term for Slavic by many accounts, but he points in particular to HaYehudim Usfas HaSlavim, see page 20 [here](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH990018925530205171/NLI) where he mentions that Rashi.

The point of HaYehudim Usfas HaSlavim was to address the Rishonim mentioning Slavic words. He doesn't seem to focus on *why* they would call the Slavic language(s) by the name Canaan, unless I missed something.

Is it related to slav = slave = eved knani?
Is it a general term for non-jews (if so why specifically slavs?) Some other reason?

Comment: Which sources say this?

Comment: I don't really know but i've definately seen it. "(Rashi refers in several places to the Slavic languages as "lashon K'naan")" https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1830/modern-nations-and-umos-haolam/137696#137696 Alex's answer

Comment: Also, does anyone actually hold there is a real connection to Cannan

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaanic_language

Comment: If you object to my edit, feel free to revert the question.